com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket (Exception in monitor thread)
I am trying to connect (Java spring boot) to an Azure Cosmo for Mongo DB and getting the following error for remote connection; but for the same code, I am able to connect to the local mongodb.
Local: (Works)
mongodb://localhost:27017
Remote: (Fails)
mongodb://:@:10255/?ssl=true?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@username@
I have been researching and googling and trying different options but still cannot figure out.
Any suggestions or advice would be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

2024-05-01 18:54:29.143  INFO 306023 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@8716901 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=XYZ.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2024-05-01 18:54:39.090  INFO 306023 --- [azure.com:10255] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server XYZ.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305) ~[na:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
        ... 4 common frames omitted


If I connect locally using the same code, but different URI, then it works.
2024-05-01 17:05:06.323  INFO 241501 --- [  restartedMain] c.g.config.allowable.config.AxonConfig   : MongoDB uri: mongodb://localhost:27017
2024-05-01 17:05:06.576  INFO 241501 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-data", "version": "4.6.1"}, "os": {"type": "Linux", "name": "Linux", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "4.18.0-372.64.1.el8_6.x86_64"}, "platform": "Java/Microsoft/11.0.16+8-LTS"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@209489fc]}, clusterSettings={hosts=[localhost:27017], srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, requiredReplicaSetName='null', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='30000 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, sendBufferSize=0}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=false, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=UNSPECIFIED, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, contextProvider=null}
2024-05-01 17:05:06.579  INFO 241501 --- [  restartedMain] c.g.config.allowable.config.AxonConfig   : EventStorageEngine: MongoClient: com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientImpl@27d102e9
2024-05-01 17:05:06.591  INFO 241501 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:978}] to localhost:27017
2024-05-01 17:05:06.594  INFO 241501 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:979}] to localhost:27017
2024-05-01 17:05:06.595  INFO 241501 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=21, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=42858025}

2024-05-01 17:05:06.642  INFO 241501 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:980}] to localhost:27017
2024-05-01 17:05:06.924  INFO 241501 --- [  restartedMain] c.g.config.allowable.config.AxonConfig   : EventStore: EventStorageEngine: org.axonframework.extensions.mongo.eventsourcing.eventstore.MongoEventStorageEngine@19305c3b



did you make sure your azure mongodb has the firewall configuration to accept public internet connections?
